# Using tweetstream and timeout

Tags: ruby, tweetstream

Ruby version: 2.0.0-p0
Mac - Mountain Lion

Following is my code (tw_stream_track.rb):

```
require 'tweetstream'

TweetStream.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key       = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  config.consumer_secret    = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  config.oauth_token        = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  config.oauth_token_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  config.auth_method        = :oauth
end

client = TweetStream::Client.new

client.on_error do |message|
  puts message
end

client.track('apple', 'microsoft', 'samsung') do |status|
  puts "#{status.text}"
end
```

When I run it from a terminal:

```
ruby tw_stream_track.rb
```

I get the following:

```
/Users/mine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/tweetstream-2.5.0/lib/tweetstream/client.rb:436:in `block in connect': Failed to reconnect after 11 tries. (TweetStream::ReconnectError)
    from /Users/mine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/em-twitter-0.2.2/lib/em-twitter/connection.rb:296:in `call'
    from /Users/mine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/em-twitter-0.2.2/lib/em-twitter/connection.rb:296:in `invoke_callback'
    from /Users/mine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/em-twitter-0.2.2/lib/em-twitter/connection.rb:268:in `rescue in schedule_reconnect'
    from /Users/mine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/em-twitter-0.2.2/lib/em-twitter/connection.rb:263:in `schedule_reconnect'
    from /Users/mine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/em-twitter-0.2.2/lib/em-twitter/connection.rb:93:in `unbind'
    from /Users/mine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:1440:in `event_callback'
    from /Users/mine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
    from /Users/mine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
    from /Users/mine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/tweetstream-2.5.0/lib/tweetstream/client.rb:388:in `start'
    from /Users/mine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/tweetstream-2.5.0/lib/tweetstream/client.rb:131:in `filter'
    from /Users/mine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/tweetstream-2.5.0/lib/tweetstream/client.rb:98:in `track'
```

This is my first time using tweetstream, and from the documentation, it seems as if this is what I'm supposed to be doing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heard TweetStream had some problems with ruby 2.0.0, did you try with ruby 1.9.3 ?

**UPDATE**

I just had a try and your code is working fine with ruby 1.9.3 (installed with rvm).
The only pb that I have is that the stream seems to stop retrieving new messages after some time.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error appeared because I was using same keys in 2 rails app instances(on staging and production servers) + 1 local(development) instance.

The 3rd instance was unable to connect to tweets stream. [It is cause because of the `twitter` limitations](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/connecting)

So I resolved this by creating dedicated twitter applications(with separate keys) for each Rails application instance.